# Creating a php page upon form submission with the name of the page named as a field

Tags: javascript, php, forms

i would like to know how to get a page duplicated upon form submission.

For example, i am registering something on a form and upon the submission on the form, the php page gets called and information on the page is saved in the database (this works fine). There are several field in this form and one named "Acronym".

Upon submission, i want a page(present in the htdoc folder as i am using XAMPP) to be duplicated with the Acronym field as the name of the new php page

Anyone can give me some information about how to do this as i have no idea how to

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into PHP's [copy function](https://secure.php.net/copy)?

Comment: $file = $_POST['acronym'].".php";
$open = fopen($file, "w");
$content= file_get_contents('mcb.php');
fwrite($open, $content);
fclose($open);

worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, websites don't create new pages for every user, but store information in a database and retrieve them. But if you want to create a new page:

`$file = $_POST['Acronym'].".php"; 
  $open = fopen($file, "w"); 
  fwrite($open, $content); 
  fclose($open)`

Enter the contents of the page in `$content`.

Comment: $file = $_POST['acronym'].".php";
$open = fopen($file, "w");
$content= file_get_contents('mcb.php');
fwrite($open, $content);
fclose($open);

Worked thank you!!

Comment: That's one heck of a workaround for `copy('mcb.php', $_POST['acronym'] . '.php');`...